# Restart php-fpm process with custom config

Tags: php

I have on my server running custom php process `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/master.d/custom_name.conf`

```
root      2620  0.0  2.6 412440 26808 ?        Ss   May31   0:33 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.1/fpm/master.d/custom_name.conf)
root      6822  0.0  0.0  13384   916 pts/1    S+   19:58   0:00 grep php
root     27575  0.0  1.1 410680 11828 ?        Ss   May31   0:33 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 27578  0.0  0.5 410680  5760 ?        S    May31   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 27579  0.0  0.5 410680  5760 ?        S    May31   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

And config exists in directory `/etc/php/fpm/master.d/custom_name.conf`.
But i don't even know how to restart this service. I changed file config and tried `service php7.1-fpm stop` but the process is still alive.

If I try `service php7.1-fpm start` or `service php7.1-fpm restart` process `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf` appears, but old process still working. Maybe command `service php7.1-fpm` has parameters where i can pass extra config data. Example config file from `master.d` directory

Here is config of this file `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/master.d/custom_name.conf`:

```
[global]
pid = /run/php7.1-fpm.custom_name.pid
error_log = /var/log/php7.1-fpm.log

[custom_name]
user = custom_name
group = custom_name
listen = /var/run/php7.1-fpm.custom_name.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.status_path = /fpm-status
chdir = /
catch_workers_output = yes
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /var/www/custom_name.com/sessions
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/www/custom_name.com/code/public:/tmp:/usr/share/php:/var/www/tools/
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[opcache.enable] = on
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: restarting your web service IE `service apache2 restart` should automatically restart the process(es), shouldn't it?

Comment: @Zak I tried to restart apache2, php processes are working.

Comment: Have you tried `/etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart` ?  I am on Ubuntu -- So your syntax might be slightly different ..

Comment: @Zak yes, i've tried. I dont know, but maybe hoster used command `start-stop-daemon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally hoster said me how restart this process:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm@custom_name restart
```